How to redirect using a custom wordpress api endpoint after form submission?
I'm using a custom wordpress endpoint that I have defined in functions.php:
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('custom_endpoint', 'submit-application', [
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'submit_application'
    ]);
});

I'm using the endpoint to process some form data sent via jetform builder. After the form data has been processed (various calls to an external api), I would like to redirect to a url that is returned by the api dynamically. Currently the business logic all succeeds, but I cannot for the life of me get the redirect to work. The form submits and displays a message "Form successfully submitted".
function submit_application ( $request ) {

  //Business logic here all succeeds

  $user= send_data($data);

  try {
      return new \WP_REST_Response(
          null, 
          303, 
          array(
              'Location' => $user['url'], 
          )
      );
      
  } catch (Exception $e) {
      return new WP_REST_Response( [
          'status' => 'error',
          'message' => $e->getMessage()
      ], 400 );
  }
}

I've also tried using
    wp_redirect( $user['url'] );
    exit();

The odd thing is I got it to work once, with what I think is this exact code, but suddenly after I continued development it stopped. It is also odd, because when I try the end point via postman instead of the form submission, it seems to receive the redirect correctly as well. Maybe that's indicative of a cache issue? I'm a little new to wordpress so any ideas would be very welcome!

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79138372/how-to-redirect-using-a-custom-wordpress-api-endpoint-after-form-submission. Please post your question in only the most appropriate site.

@Caleb sorry, assumed they would be different communities. Just trying to figure this out and feeling a bit frustrated.

Have you tried var_dump( $user['url'] ) to see what it is you're getting?

If you're using javascript to submit the form data to the REST endpoint, then you should handle the redirection at the client side, not at the server with PHP. Read the location header from the response and pass it to window.location to redirect the user somewhere.
Here's a simplified example - not tested, requires fleshing out.
document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    submitViaRestApi(event)
        .then(response => redirectToLocation(response.location))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
});

function redirectToLocation(location) {
    // like a mouse click
    // window.location.href = location;
    // or
    // a HTTP redirect
    // window.location.replace(location);
    // Learn about window.location at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location
}

function submitViaRestApi(event) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // send data to REST endpoint
    });
}


Hi, thanks! I would be comfortable doing this via js, but since I am using jetform instead of a more custom solution, I'm not very sure where I would include the promise logic? Any ideas?

Unfortunately not, I'm not familiar with jetform. You'll have to either dig into their documentation or ask via their support channels, if they provide a js API, which you can use to perform custom actions before/after the form submission on the client side. Or just try hijacking the form's submit event with your own js.
And I'm afraid questions about third party plugins, e.g. jetform, aren't well suited to this stack as they are considered off-topic here. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Sure that makes sense. I was thinking of hijacking the submit event as well, but wasn't sure where to start doing that. Maybe in a custom html block? But then I'm not sure if I will have access to the data being submitted.

Personally, I'd create a separate js file and enqueue it with wp_enqueue_script() instead of using a custom HTML block. This way the different responsibilities would stay nicely separated. If you attach a custom submit event listener to the form with js, then you'll need to pick up the input data from the form (event.target) yourself for example with a new FormData object.

Nice this idea was what ultimately led to me solving the problem, though thankfully it actually turned out to be much simpler. I posted the answer here in case anyone finds it helpful in the future. Thanks again for your help!

It sounds like the issue might be related to how the response is being handled after the API submission. The 303 status code with the Location header is correct for a redirect, but there may be some form-handling logic that's preventing it from being followed.
A possible solution would be to ensure that after the form submission, the page properly redirects when receiving the API response. You can also try using wp_redirect directly inside your callback, ensuring it's done before returning the response. Here’s an updated version of your code:
function submit_application($request) {

    // Business logic here
    $user = send_data($data);

    try {
        // Direct redirect using wp_redirect
        wp_redirect($user['url']);
        exit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return new WP_REST_Response([
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ], 400);
    }
}

The key difference here is making sure wp_redirect and exit() are executed before sending the response back. If the API endpoint is directly interacting with the front end, this should trigger a proper redirect.
By the way, which hosting are you using? Some hosting providers handle caching and server-side configurations differently, which could affect things like dynamic redirects. I’ve been using Cloudways, and I like how they handle caching and other optimizations while keeping things easy to manage. It might be worth exploring if server-side issues are causing conflicts.
